# PHP Issues with <textarea> in a Form

Tags: php, forms, text, textarea, area

Forgive me for asking such a basic question, I am a beginner and not too familiar with PHP in general but I've looked around and have not found an IE compatible solution to my issue.

I used W3 schools: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_textarea.asp & http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_textarea_form.asp to find this out.

I am making a basic PHP form, in part of the form I have a  for users to fill in and then pass the value to a variable to email off. Anyways, I've found a solution that works in Chrome/Opera/Mozilla but not IE, that is to use the form "id" tag.

```
<form method='post' id='usrform' action='form.php'>
<textarea name='details' form='usrform' rows='8' cols='60'></textarea>
</form>
```

So that I can do this.

```
$contents = $_REQUEST['details'];
```

Hopefully I have explained this well enough. :)

Comment: What doesn't work in IE? What's the behavior?

Comment: `$contents = $_REQUEST['details'];` should work fine...

Comment: w3schools isn’t really the best place to begin, though. http://w3fools.com/

Comment: It simply does nothing, the page submits and the rest of the form data  goes through without issue but its as if the $contents variable is completely empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
$contents = $_POST['details'];
```

instead of

```
$contents = $_REQUEST['details'];
```

Comment: Hey this seemed to work! Thank you!! Any reason for this? I thought a $_REQUEST would be appropriate. I'd upvote you but I'm too new. ;)

Comment: You don't need reputation to mark as answer. Just click the "check" near the upvote and downvote buttons. :)

Comment: $_REQUEST should work exactly the same as long as you don't modify the $_POST or $_GET during runtime. $_REQUEST contains all post, get, and cookie superglobals.

Comment: $_GET is for forms that pass through the URL, (method='get'), $_POST is for forms that utilize method='post', and $_COOKIE is for cookies (little snippet of data, not securely, but saved on the browser). PRPGFerret is right, $_REQUEST should work for all of them, but it didn't in this case. :| I did read though that's it's generally better to use $_REQUEST, $_COOKIE OR $_POST when you are able. Glad my answer helped. Oh, and PLEASE mark as correct answer. :)

Comment: Awesome, thanks a ton guys that was a quick answer. It didn't let me mark it right away, I guess it has a 15 minute timer.

Comment: @Darek Gajda No problem! But please mark it when it lets you... it improves my reputation and privileges. :)